# What is the difference between: `tx.wait()` and `await tx.wait()`

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have this code :

```js
const tx = await game.win();

receipt =await tx.wait();
```

can someone explain if we are already using wait is there a need to use await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing

```
receipt =await tx.wait();
```

you are awaiting that the method wait() finish, that indeed awaits the result of the transaction, if you would not `await` the code will continue executing before the transaction has finished

Hope it helps!